# Is there a more elegant way of doing these bitwise operations?

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation

I built this program that does some bitwise operations on three numbers: 2, 4 and 20:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mask = 63;
    int id = 2;
    id = (id << 6) | 4;
    id = (id << 6) | 20;
    int v3 = id & mask;
    int v2 = (id >> 6) & mask;
    int v1 = (id >> 6*2) & mask;
    System.out.println(v1 + " " + v2 + " " + v3);
}
```

I have no doubts about the bitwise operation, but I don't know if this is the best way of doing that.
Is there a more elegant way of doing these operations?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: p.s. for a 6 bit shift the mask should be 63, not 127.

Comment: I understand bitwise ops pretty well and I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.  What do you want in which variables and what are you trying to represent?

Comment: it _looks_ like he's trying to pack three six-bit values into an int

Comment: you're write, 6 bit it's 63... I'll change the mask.

Comment: I just want to find a more "elegant" way of doing that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming that your intent is to pack three six-bit values into a single `int`, in which case:

```
public int pack(int v1, int v2, int v3) {
    return (v3 & 0x3f) <<  0 |
           (v2 & 0x3f) <<  6 |
           (v1 & 0x3f) << 12;
}

public void unpack(int n) {
    int v3 = (n >>  0) & 0x3f;
    int v2 = (n >>  6) & 0x3f;
    int v1 = (n >> 12) & 0x3f;
    // do stuff with v1, v2, v3
}
```

It's *functionally* much the same as your code, to be honest, but I would hope that the intent is somewhat clearer.

The `<< 0` and `>> 0` operations *should* be optimised away by the compiler, but are shown for "symmetry"

Comment: Actually, java compiler doesn't
  public void unpack(int n);
   0  iload_1 [n]
   1  iconst_0
   2  ishr
   3  bipush 63
   5  iand
   6  istore_2 [v3]
   7  iload_1 [n]
   8  bipush 6
  10  ishr
  11  bipush 63
  13  iand
  14  istore_3 [v2]
  15  iload_1 [n]
  16  bipush 12
  18  ishr
  19  bipush 63
  21  iand
  22  istore 4 [v1]
  24  return

Comment: @JarekPrzygódzki wow, that's pretty lame...  thanks for checking it, though!

Comment: I'd use `const int mask = (1<<6)-1;` instead of hardcoding `0x3f`. Makes it clearer that we're working on 6 bit chunks.

Comment: @MSalters sure, if you can't do that sort of thing in your head ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In C or C++ you can use bitfields to automate this:

```
struct BitField {
    int v1 : 6;
    int v2 : 6;
    int v3 : 6;
};
```

although if you need to guarantee it fits in int64_t, you may need to explicitly disable padding (or enable packing) depending on your compiler.

Comment: There is no actual guarantee that such `BitField` would be laid in memory as you propose it will, is one of those implementation defined features.

Comment: True; in fact, I didn't make any proposal for how it would be laid out, and since the OP didn't specify whether the requirement is compatible layout, reduced space or something else ... I just put it out there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I think it is a better practice to have constants with bits set as appropriate. If trying to store multiple values in a single int as suggested in the comments, maybe something like...

```
private static int VALUE_1_MASK = 0x0000003F;
private static int VALUE_2_MASK = 0x00000FB0;
private static int VALUE_3_MASK = 0x0003F000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int mask = 127;
   int v3 = (mask & VALUE_3_MASK) >> 12;
   int v2 = (mask & VALUE_2_MASK) >> 6;
   int v1 = mask & VALUE_1_MASK;
   System.out.println(v1 + " " + v2 + " " + v3);
}
```

If doing this in Java I would create an enum for the mask values and have a method in the enum that would get the value.

Comment: It should be `VALUE_2_MASK = 0x00000FC0` not `FB0`. Also, `mask & VALUE_3_MASK` is always zero.